# Cannot powermock ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, testing, junit, powermock, processbuilder

I've got problems powermocking `ProcessBuilder`'s constructor. The `ProcessBuilder` object is not mocked and instead `new` returns `null`. Code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Runner {
    private ProcessBuilder processBuilder;

    public ProcessBuilder getProcessBuilder() {
        return processBuilder;
    }

    public void run() {
        processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("command", "parameter");
    }

    public void runInSubclass() {
        final SubRunner subRunner = new SubRunner();
        subRunner.run();
    }

    public void runInThread() {
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(new SubRunner());
    }

    private class SubRunner extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("command", "parameter");
        }
    }
}
```

Tests (all of them fail):

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.whenNew;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Runner.class)
public class RunnerTest {
    private Runner runner;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        runner = new Runner();
        ProcessBuilder processBuilderMock = mock(ProcessBuilder.class);

        whenNew(ProcessBuilder.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(processBuilderMock);
    }

    @Test
    public void run() throws Exception {
        runner.run();
        assertThat(runner.getProcessBuilder(), is(not(nullValue())));
    }

    @Test
    public void runInSubclass() throws Exception {
        runner.runInSubclass();
        assertThat(runner.getProcessBuilder(), is(not(nullValue())));
    }

    @Test
    public void runInThread() throws Exception {
        runner.runInThread();
        Thread.sleep(100);
        assertThat(runner.getProcessBuilder(), is(not(nullValue())));
    }
}
```

I'm using the lastest PowerMock (1.6.6).

Comment: `I've got problems ...` please, explain what exactly happens and why it's a problem

Comment: @defaultlocale, updated. new returns null and all test fail.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need PowerMock to solve this.

Your problem is that you are calling **new** all over the place in your production code. Instead, you could use dependency injection, like:

```
public class Runner {
...

  public Runner() {
    this ( new ProcessBuilder() );
  }

  Runner(ProcessBuilder builder) {...
```

and all of a sudden you have a "telescoped" constructor that allows you to **inject** your dependency (a ProcessBuilder object). And all of a sudden your need to use PowerMock to call *new* vanishes.

The point is: PowerMock is "expensive"; as it has quite some "bad" side effects. Simply avoid using it.

Beyond that: PowerMock should do the job quite fine; simply check your code against their instructions (to be found [here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockconstructor)); but as said: the real answer is to **not** use PowerMock for stuff like this. Instead: learn to write [testable](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79) code.

Comment: Totally agree: "Simply avoid using it." and "Learn to write testable code."